# ANnswering myself - uitableview - ios7 - cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout

I am using a uivewcontroller with an embedded uitableview created using storyboard.

The tableview was set to use my custom view controller.

It was set to have "dynamic prototypes".

The cell had the reuse identifier correctly set.

I didn't need to register cell reuse identifier for my cell manually as it was created using storyboard. But I still tried.

Table view was also set correctly to use my custom view controller for datasource and delegate (which a lot of SO posts talked about). I also added an outlet to my tableview in my view controller and manually called `[mytableview2.delegate=self; [mytableview2.dataSource=self;` Still no luck.

I was loading the data into the array before my tableview `numberofrowsinsection` was called, so that wasn't the issue.

I also tried adding `[mytableview reloadData]` statements after loading the data in the `viewDidLoad` method. No dice.

Cell height was set to 120 (not zero as was the case in some other SO posts).

I also changed the background color of my view, table view and cells to different colors (gray, yellow, red). But all I would see in simulator was gray. So tableview and cell wasn't even shown.

To debug, I put NSLog and break points at the "`numberofrowsinsection`", "`numberofsections`" and "`Cellforrowatindexpath`".

The numberofrowsinsection, numberofsections were called and confirmed that my array was not empty. They returned positive counts. **But my `cellforrowatindexpath` never got called**.

After pulling my hair for couple hours, I found the issue.

**I had used Xcode's storyboard autolayout option "Add missing constraints" to automatically add constraints to my table view. This was the issue! As soon as I deleted all the constraints, my tableview cells apppeared right away!! I didn't find this in any of the SO posts, so hope this helps someone else!** So if you face a similar issue and have confirmed everything above is setup correctly, then try deleting all the constraints on your tableview!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I had used Xcode's storyboard autolayout option "Add missing constraints" to automatically add constraints to my table view. This was the issue! As soon as I deleted all the constraints, my tableview cells apppeared right away!! I didn't find this in any of the SO posts, so hope this helps someone else!** So if you face a similar issue and have confirmed everything above is setup correctly, then try deleting all the constraints on your tableview and testing! Then manually adding constraints one by one correctly manually.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will just add that even if auto layout doesn't show any warning or errors, it happened